# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So, in my next app, i'm using `react-google-one-tap-login` library that has `useGoogleOneTapLogin` hooks and must be call inside of react component. But when i call it like:

```js
func() {
  useGoogleOneTapLogin({})
  return (some jsx)
}
```

I got an error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

Then, i'll try to fix it using if (process.browser) then run `useGoogleOneTapLogin`, but i got an error: `useGoogleOneTapLogin is called conditionally, hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render`. BUT, this is only occur when i'll try to deploy the app.

Then, once again i'll try to fix by call it inside `useEffect` for the first time comp load, by also got an error: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: This is not inside a function component, this is inside `func` which is not a function component.

Comment: Bruh that just for simplified

Comment: But it is exactly the error message you get, so I suspect you have the same problem in your code.

Comment: Hooks can only be called in the body of function components (i.e. not in callbacks/inner functions) or in the body of custom hooks, and they cannot be called conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MSalmanTariq/react-google-one-tap-login/issues/13#issuecomment-1056016843

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const GoogleOneTapLogin = dynamic(() => import('react-google-one-tap-login'))
  
  return (
    <GoogleOneTapLogin
        onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
        onSuccess={(response) => console.log(response)}
        googleAccountConfigs={{ client_id: 'example.apps.googleusercontent.com' }}
      />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call hooks inside conditions per react documentation. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

To solve your issue if your hook depends on window object or you want to client side rendering, you can delay rendering your component only on client side.

```js
// Create a component called ClientOnly
// components/ClientOnly.js

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ClientOnly({ children, ...rest}) {
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!hasMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div {...rest}>{children}</div>;
}
```

then, wrap your component with this component

```js
  <ClientOnly>
    <YourGoogleOneTapLoginComponent />
  </ClientOnly>
```

To read more about this pattern, See: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration